# Include schema generation in openjpa:sql task

Tags: java, maven, database-schema, openjpa, openjpa-maven-plugin

I'm using the `openjpa-maven-plugin` to generate DDL files from my OpenJPA persistence entities. For example:

```
@Entity
@Table(schema = "myschema", name = "mytable")
public class MyEntity {
    ....
}
```

The `openjpa:sql` task generates the following DDL:

```sql
CREATE TABLE myschema.mytable (...);
```

If I run this DDL on a new DB, it would complain about the missing `myschema` schema. So the ideal DDL output would be:

```sql
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS myschema;
CREATE TABLE myschema.mytable (...);
```

Is there a way to tell the Maven plugin to also add in that extra SQL statement to create the schema?